# if statement & jQuery :contains

Tags: jquery, if-statement, contains

I have a table with unstyled links in it so I want to wrap these links in divs and style them via Bootstrap classes. I am having trouble with the .contains() function and I might need some help with the if statement as well.

Here is my code so far, and here is a link, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/LFb6M/

```
// Add Bootstrap button classes to Admin links
if($('td.menu-operations a:contains("add")') {
$(this).css('color','white').wrap('<div class="btn btn-inverse btn-mini" />');
}
else if($('td.menu-operations a:contains("edit")') {
$(this).css('color','white').wrap('<div class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" />');
}
else if($('td.menu-operations a:contains("delete")') {
$(this).css('color','white').wrap('<div class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" />');
}
else ($('td.menu-operations a')){
$(this).css('color','white').wrap('<div class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" />');
}
```

Thanks heaps :)

Comment: `if($('td.menu-operations a').text().indexOf('add')){`. I personally hate `:contains()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out I didnt need an if statement to solve this problem. Thanks to @Musa for pointing that out and setting me on the right track. I was able to work out what to do from his answer. I would have marked that as correct but I felt it needed to be fleshed out a bit more so it was easier to understand.

You can see it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/LFb6M/15/

```
// Add Bootstrap button classes to Admin links
$('td.menu-operations a').css('color','white').wrap('<div class="btn btn-mini" />');
$('td.menu-operations a:contains("add")').parent().addClass('btn-primary');
$('td.menu-operations a:contains("edit")').parent().addClass('btn-inverse');
$('td.menu-operations a:contains("delete")').parent().addClass('btn-danger');
```

What happens above is we wrap all links in a div with the default Bootstrap classes using .wrap(), then we use the :contains selector to target links with specific text and then target the newly generated div using .parent() and add the appropriate class via .addClass()

PS: When using :contains be careful to use the selector and not the default .contains() function because this does not work with text.

Comment: For those interested I discovered another selector called the Attribute Contains Selector. This will allow you to check if for instance your ID or HREF contains the word you are looking for. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Doing `if($(selector))` will always evaluate true, the correct version is `if($(selector).length)`, but in this case no `if` is needed. Also you use `this` as if it will change in each if block(it won't)

```
// Add Bootstrap button classes to Admin links
$('td.menu-operations a:contains("add")').css('color','white');
$('td.menu-operations a:contains("edit")').css('color','white');
$('td.menu-operations a:contains("delete")').css('color','white');
$('td.menu-operations a').css('color','white').wrap('<div class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" />');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LFb6M/11/

Comment: `.indexOf()`! Plse make this `:contains()` thing go away with me, lol.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy why do you hate `:contains`?

Comment: Thanks but that wraps the link in two divs

Comment: If (this) won't change in each block can you suggest another method that will change. So I can just target that link I want? Thanks

Comment: @ClintonGreen ... select them with jQuery as shown in the answer

Comment: [This is why I hate :contains](http://jsperf.com/jquery-contains-selector-vs-indexof)

Comment: I got it working like this, thanks for your help. http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/LFb6M/14/
@Ohgodwhy I tried .indexOf but no luck looks like :contains is here to stay ;)